# Multiprocessing pipes on windows with python

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pipe

Does Windows support multithreading.pipes()? If yes, then what is wrong with this code? Do I need to be using reduction? The code hangs on p2.recv() and I get a RuntimeError when run from the command line.

```
import multiprocessing
def ProcessCreator(pipe):
    pipe.send("hello from other process")

p1, p2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = ProcessCreator, args = (p2,))
proc.start()
print p1.recv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need put pipe code into **if __name__ == '__main__'** part.([Why?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)) And change **p2.recv** to **p1.recv**

```
import multiprocessing
def ProcessCreator(pipe):
    pipe.send("hello from other process")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    p1, p2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = ProcessCreator, args = (p2,))
    proc.start()
    print p1.recv()
```