# How to exchange data via Pipe in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm studying multiprocessing in Python and am trying to make 2 processes and exchange data between them via Pipe.

In the code below, I expected `sender` to send a random integer to `receiver` every second, and `receiver` writes the value to the file `multi.txt`.

But the file's empty even after running the code. What would be the problem of this code? Have I misunderstood something or made mistakes somewhere?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import os

pipe1, pipe2 = mp.Pipe()  


class sender(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print('SENDER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            value = random.randint(0, 10)
            pipe1.send(value)
            #print(pipe2.recv())    # <--- prints out value without problems
            time.sleep(1)


class receiver(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print('RECEIVER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            #print(pipe2.recv())     # <--- doesn't print out value or write it to file
            os.chdir('C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\NEW_TRO')
            file = open("multi.txt", "a")
            file.write(pipe2.recv())
            file.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('MAIN PID: ', os.getpid() )

    p1 = sender()
    p2 = receiver()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

#mp.freeze_support()
```

Comment: You need to close the file.

Comment: @James Thank you for your answer. I fixed the code, but it still doesn't write data to the file or prints out data.

Comment: your comment is "# <--- doesn't print out value or write it to file" but I copied your code, stripped out the file part and uncommented the print statement in receiver and you code ran fine for me. I would suggest you simplify your code, get it working just using prints and then add your file write back in

Comment: @TheDavidFactor Thank you for testing the code. I think I should try running the code on a different os or computer..

Comment: It was due to the fact I use Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409992/multiprocessing-pipes-on-windows-with-python